# GetProcAddress vs __declspec( dllimport )

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ntdll

What's the difference between the two?

i.e. for finding functions such as Nt___ or Zw___

Comment: really `__declspec(dllimport)` only effect that *CL* declare pointer to symbol (function) and call function (or access data) via this pointer. all. real effect give use import library in build process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Windos, there is a difference between **implicit linking** and **explicit linking**.

Implicit Linking

The executable is linked against the accompanying library (`.lib` file) which provides the symbols exported from DLL. (The functions for import are remarked with `__declspec(dllimport)`.) Implicit linked DLLs are loaded with executable.

Explicit Linking

The program loads a DLL explicitly calling `LoadLibrary()`. To call functions of the DLL their address has to be determined using `GetProcAddress()`.

However, [`GetProcAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used as well for functions which come from implicit linked DLLs. This can be helpful, if accidentally the same symbol is available in multiple DLLs (e.g. if DLLs have been used which are linked against different runtime DLLs).

Sometimes, DLLs are provided without import libraries. A wellknown example is OpenGL for which MS stopped support with version 1.2. However, with sufficient H/W and up-to-date drivers, all functions of the current OpenGL version might be availabe (and can be loaded with `GetProcAdress()` at run-time).

A piece of sample code for OpenGL binding `MyGL.cc`:

```
  // version 2.0
  glAttachShader
    = (PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress(
      "glAttachShader");
  glCompileShader
    = (PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress(
      "glCompileShader");
  glCreateProgram
    = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress(
      "glCreateProgram");
  glCreateShader
    = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress(
      "glCreateShader");
  glDeleteProgram
    = (PFNGLDELETEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress(
      "glDeleteProgram");
  glDeleteShader
    = (PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress(
      "glDeleteShader");
```

with `MyGL.h`:

```
// Version 2.0
extern MY_GL_API PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC glAttachShader;
extern MY_GL_API PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC glCompileShader;
extern MY_GL_API PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC glCreateProgram;
extern MY_GL_API PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader;
extern MY_GL_API PFNGLDELETEPROGRAMPROC glDeleteProgram;
extern MY_GL_API PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC glDeleteShader;
```

where `MY_GL_API` is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` when `MyGL.dll` is compiled and `__declspec(dllimport)` otherwise. (So, actually `__declspec(dllimport)` **and** `GetProcAddress()` instead of *vs.* as function pointers themselves are `dllexport`ed but initialized at run-time unsing `GetProcAddress()`.)

(The `PFNGL` macros expand to function pointer types with the appropriate signature. They are included from a header provided by [kronos.org](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php).)

Another important usage of `GetProcAddress()` is for functions which may exist not before a certain version of Windows (or other functions which may or may not be available in DLLs). Thus, the application can be written backwards compatible providing an alternative fall-back when `GetProcAddress()` fails for the intended function.

The sample provided on MSDN for `GetProcAddress()`:

```
typedef void (WINAPI *PGNSI)(LPSYSTEM_INFO);

// Call GetNativeSystemInfo if supported or GetSystemInfo otherwise.

   PGNSI pGNSI;
   SYSTEM_INFO si;

   ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(SYSTEM_INFO));

   pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(
      GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), 
      "GetNativeSystemInfo");
   if (NULL != pGNSI) {
      pGNSI(&si);
   } else {
       GetSystemInfo(&si);
   }
```

Further reading: [MSDN: Link an executable to a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=vs-2017)

Comment: How does the compiler know, from implicit linking, that the function is stored in a DLL called ntdll? Upvote for thorough answer :)

Comment: @CryptographyMan There is an C++ example in the linked [`GetProcAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) page.

Comment: I know how GetProcAddress works, I'm currently using it and it works fine. dllimport looks easier and I'd like to compare it do GetProcAddress with regard to antianalysis

Comment: @CryptographyMan If implicit linking is an option, so use it. `GetProcAddress()` is for the cases where implicit linking is not an option. (I gave two examples how this can happen.)

Comment: The other reason for using `GetProcAddress` is for DLL's where you have no import library and the only option left is to use `GetProcAddress`, unless you have a tool to create import libraries from existing DLL's.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for pointing this out - extended the answer a bit.

Comment: A further reason for using `GetProcAddress` instead of import libraries -- if you're trying to write code that could be used on various Windows C++ compilers, then the usage of import libraries becomes somewhat cumbersome, since different compiler brands have different import library formats.  By using `GetProcAddress`, the import library differences between compilers becomes a moot point.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is beyond my experience. So, I leave it as comment. ;-) I know about differences of VS versions concerning C++. We either prevent mixing of versions or just use a C API to come around.

Comment: A more important, significant distinction: This is comparing load-time linking to runtime-linking. This has implications on when imports are resolved, as well as what guarantees the code linking against those libraries can assume (ignoring delay-loaded modules). @pau: `GetProcAddress` takes the exported symbol as input. Since compilers do not agree on a symbol decoration scheme, you have gained nothing over using an import library.

Comment: @CryptographyMan *How does the compiler know* compiler does not know this. it simply generate variable `__imp_FuncName` and call function via it. the linker search `__imp_FuncName` symbol. if found it in import library - here exist info about dll name, from which function is imported. he put `__imp_FuncName` variable in *IAT* and create record for it/dll in import table. loader use this record to resolve function address for you, when dll loaded

Answer (score 0):

`GetProcAddress()` lets you find functions in runtime. It's useful for optional imports or for things like plug-ins that can be loaded dynamically. Another use for it is for undocumented functions that are exported but don't have a header file or library file.

Using `__declspec( dllimport )` adds the function to your import table so it's loaded automatically with your executable.

Comment: Regarding antianalysis, which is harder to detect? I assume GetProcAddress since it's runtime, but I wouldn't personally know :/

Comment: That's a separate question, but they're both easy. Check out [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: One's static in the binary, the other is conditional on call, right?

Comment: Yes, that sums it up.

Comment: *Using __declspec( dllimport ) adds the function to your import table* strictly say no. it simply equ to declare `extern "C" { extern void* __imp_FuncName; }` and call function via this pointer. than we need somehow implement `void* __imp_FuncName`. possible and direct yourself. but usual, when it implemented in import lib - yes, linker add this variable to *IAT* and create record in import table

Comment: also if we mark dll as delayload - it will be added to delay load descriptor instead