# how to create instance of some class that define in other dll/lib?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I still learn how to work with cpp .. so maybe my question are stupid but i don't find those answer to my question.

I define new project that will compile as .lib

To this project i add some class with function - this is the header.

```
class __declspec(dllexport) MyMath
{
public:
     MyMath();
    ~MyMath();

     void Print(std::string str);
 };
```

Now, I add new project that is compile as .exe and will use the MyMathLib.lib

The .exe need to import (somehow) the lib and create instance of the MyMath class - and i don't know how to do it ( the import thing )

I know how to point on the lib - but there is some places that i need to add the .h file of the MyMath class - to make the linkage available.

How to do it ?

add screenshot [image]

[image]

Comment: If you have a project for your lib/dll and another for your executable, than the easiest way is to make a solution with these two projects and add the dll/lib project as dependency to the executable project. [MSDN: How to: Create and remove project dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2017). Isn't that similar in C#? (Sorry, I'm no expert concerning C#.)

Comment: @Scheff : i already saw that you add - there is no explain how to do it do it beside the dependencies of project ( that i already know ) - but how to use it ? how to make instance of a class that exist on the lib ?

Comment: OK. Got you wrong. That's not about VS it's about C++. 1.) You need a header with declaration (beside of your .cc file with implementation). 2.) You may `#include` that header into other headers or C++ sources. This way, the other translation unit "knows" about the declaration of that class and may use it (e.g. for instancing). The rest is the job of the linker to link all that things together properly. (Sorry, these things should be found in every serious C++ tutorial. Or, I still got you wrong.)

Comment: this is not help because i still can't make the import of the class to my project

Comment: Try to just use the header you provided in the question in the exe project, replacing `dllexport` to `dllimport`

Comment: add screenshot to show what wrong - don't understand how to do it ...

Comment: AFAIK, a `class` cannot be `extern "C"`. This doesn't work! `extern "C"` is good to give a C++ lib. a C API (e.g. prevent name mangling) but, of course, a C API has to conform to C. There are no classes in C (beside of a lot of other things).

Comment: @Scheff : i still learn ... i know i made some mistakes .. - but i want to do an import class from lib to exe

Comment: Btw. I recently wrote something about explicit vs. implicit linking and gave an example for a GL binding which uses both. It might provide a clue: [SO: GetProcAddress vs __declspec( dllimport )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52341759/7478597).

Comment: _i know i made some mistakes_ Yeah - that's why you are here. ;-) I just saw that I included in my answer a link to MSDN which is still active (not yet rotten) and may be a good start to MSDN articles about your issue. Alternatively, I tried [`google "c++ declspec site:stackoverflow.com"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+declspec+site%3Astackoverflow.com) which might provide interesting answers as well. (Sorry, I was not aware that you meant _import_ literally in your question.)

Comment: solve it .. add the way i got it work

Comment: So, my 2nd comment was actually the right advise? Heavy birth... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff yes .. start something new its always not easy :) -   thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ... solve it .. now its work.

add screenshot to make things short :)

[image]